# Можно ли закачать файлы скрипта сайта через протокол sftp?

Tags: linux, vps, vds, sftp, filezilla

У меня стоит VDS, я установил веб сервер. И через FileZilla, я подключился к серверу через протокол sftp порт: 22, и закачал скрипт веб-сайта. Вопрос: Это правильно так делать? И могут ли быть ошибки в будущем? Просто после таких махинации, у меня все работает, но я беспокоюсь, т.к я слышал, что обычно загрузку файлов делают через протокол 21, но мой сервер не поддерживает его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sftp современнее и безопасней. Добавив сервис ftp (21) вы сделаете себе на сервере новую потенциальную дыру.

Comment: Т.е то что я закачал на сервер файлы по протоколу sftp через FileZilla ничего в этом страшного нет и это нормально?

Comment: это даже хорошо

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ

Comment: Нажмите на галочку слева